# How can I find out if my app has admin consent?

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am writing a web app using the Security API within Microsoft Graph and I'm authenticating with Azure AD, but the permissions needed to access the API require admin consent for every tenant that uses my app.

How can I check if the tenant admin has given consent to my app? That way I know whether to send the user to the regular login flow or to the admin consent flow.

Is it possible to make a REST call to Azure AD for this information? I’ve tried using [`oAuth2PermissionGrant`](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/oauth2permissiongrant)  but that only seems to work with the Object ID and I only have my app/client ID.

**Edit**:

I was confused about which scopes were needed in my app, but it turns out that when I add the admin only delegated permissions like `SecurityEvents.Read.All` and `SecurityEvents.ReadWrite.All` to just the [Application Registraion Portal](https://apps.dev.microsoft.com) and only use the `User.Read` permission in my app to request the users basic info. There are two different outcomes when requesting an access token;

- If the admin hasn't given my app consent, then the access token will only contain `User.Read` scope.
- If the admin has given consent, then the access token will contain `User.Read`, `SecurityEvents.Read.All`, and `SecurityEvents.ReadWrite.All` delegated scopes. Even though my app only requests `User.Read`.

I found that I can use this to determine if the admin has given consent to my app by checking the access token scopes. If it contains `SecurityEvents.Read.All`, or `SecurityEvents.ReadWrite.All` then the user can continue in the app. But if those delegated permissions are not in the scope then I can prompt the `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/adminconsent?client_id=<APP ID>&state=12345&redirect_uri=http://localhost/myapp/permissions` admin consent flow to request the permissions to be added to the tenant.

Thank you @marc-lafleur, I was using the admin account to play with the `oAuth2PermissionGrant` in Graph Explorer and I didn't catch the chicken vs. egg scenario until you pointed it out.

Answer (score 5):

When you execute Admin Consent, it appends the following query parameters to your `redirect_uri`:

```
tenant={id}&admin_consent={bool}
```

- `tenant` - This is the globally unique Id for the tenant that just executed Admin Consent.
- `admin_consent` - This is a boolean value that tells if you Admin Consent was granted (`true`) or rejected (`false`).

Typically you would capture and store these values. When you need to determine if Admin Consent needs to be requested, you can look them up from within your application.

It is also a good idea to store the date/time as well. This will allow you to re-request consent if your registered scopes have changed since they originally consented to them.

As to a Graph endpoint, this wouldn't help you very much. Since you need to have a valid token in order to call into the Graph, and you need Admin Consent before you can obtain that token, locking it within Graph itself would be present a Chicken vs. Egg scenario; you wouldn't be able to check if they had consented *until* they consented.

That said, you can determine consent using the `servicePrincipal` and `oAuth2PermissionGrant` resources:

1. First, you need to find the `id` for your app's [`servicePrinipal` using your `appId`](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer?request=servicePrincipals?$filter=appId%20eq%20'00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000'&method=GET&version=beta&GraphUrl=https://graph.microsoft.com).

   ```
   /beta/servicePrincipals?$filter=appId eq '{appId}'
   ```
2. From the response to the previous query, grab the `id` and use that to [retrieve the `oAuth2PermissionGrants`](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer?request=oauth2PermissionGrants?$filter=consentType%20eq%20'AllPrincipals'%20and%20resourceId%20eq%20'8b44c67b-91cc-4488-af9b-94a248357254'&method=GET&version=beta&GraphUrl=https://graph.microsoft.com) for your application.

   ```
   /beta/oauth2PermissionGrants?$filter=resourceId eq '{servicePrincipal.id}'
   ```

*Please note that these are `/beta` endpoints and not suitable for production use.*

Comment: If you want *production-usable* endpoints, then this is the one scenario where Azure AD Graph API is still the recommended one. And as an additional detail, the `oauth2PermissionGrant` will have `"consentType": "AllPrincipals"` and `"principalId": null` for the admin consent.

Answer (score 0):

Replacing the values of this link with the values of your app will take you to the authorization page.

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/adminconsent?client_id=6731de76-14a6-49ae-97bc-6eba6914391e&state=12345&redirect_uri=http://localhost/myapp/permissions
```

You can also use

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/<Tenant_Id>/oauth2/authorize?client_id=<App Id>&response_type=code&redirect_uri=x-msauth-com-microsoft-testApp://com.microsoft.testApp&prompt=admin_consent
```

It wi;; take you to a page where the app can be authorized or let you know the status if you don't have admin privileges.